# Https in flutter -post do not accept integer

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried a lot to pass the int to the id via post but it didn't work and I used tostrin() but the api refuses to be an id string so what is the solution

```
http.Response response = await http.post(url,body:{
"id": id.toString(),"customerName":name.Text,"address": address.Text,"isMale": true.toString};
```

[image: api image]
Note: These entries are for clarification, and they are now fake. How can I send an api intger via http? If I convert it to a string, how do I make the API accept it?

Comment: Have you tried not converting it to a string? The request example shows an integer, so you should send it as an integer. Same should go for the isMale value - it should be boolean, not string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json.encode() like below (Also I believe you can pass the id as integer)

```
     body: json.encode(
        {
          'id': id.toString(),
          'customerName':name.Text,
          'address': address.Text,
          'isMale': true.toString,
        },
      ),
```

[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)[dart](/questions/tagged/dart)[http](/questions/tagged/http)